# vcpkg and cmake and vsc on Ubuntu can not find package

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, vcpkg

I installed vcpkg on Ubuntu 20.04 and install boost and opencv.

I have this cmakelist file:

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /home/m/local/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE STRING "")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-linux" CACHE STRING "")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(test1 VERSION 0.1.0)
    
find_package(Opencv CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(boost CONFIG REQUIRED )
    
add_executable(test1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test1 PRIVATE opencv::opencv boost::boost)
```

but when I run it inside Visual studio code, it can not find openCV and boost.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: You have to delete the whole build directory when you set the toolchain file.

Comment: Once you create the build directory with the CMake cache in it, it cannot change toolchain file.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I deleted the build directory and closed VCS and restart vsc. Still the same error. Any other idea?

Comment: Try setting the toolchain file in the command line arguments instead.

Comment: I am using visual studio code and cmake tools extension, how can I do this in this setup?

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required` should be the first command: some scripts (and probably toolchains) could take a version into the account. Correct name of packages is `OpenCV` and `Boost` (case matters!). And show the output of configuration process. At least, for make sure that the toolchain is actually applied.

Comment: @mans that would be in your workspace settings, search for "cmake configure args"

Comment: @Tsyvarev Changing opencv to OpenCV did the trick for opencv and it can find it, but for Boost, none of the boost or Boost works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case matters in CMake as mentioned in the comments:

```
find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

and

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
```

vcpkg does not install config files for Boost, so you cannot use `CONFIG` here. You probably also want to call it with the `COMPONENTS` option to list the modules you actually want.

Usage from vcpkg:

```
The package boost is compatible with built-in CMake targets:

    find_package(Boost REQUIRED [COMPONENTS <libs>...])
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```